# App for iPhone that can stitch images of a whiteboard

Tags: images, ios, stitching

When designing software I often draw large images on a whiteboard.
The image is often too large to fit on one photo, so I take several pictures with my iPhone, and then stitch them together.

Unfortunately, the stitch apps I used so far (AutoStitch, Photosynth, ...) all assume that you are taking pictures of a panorama, not a flat whiteboard, which results in strange deformed images.

Is there a good iPhone app that can stitch images taken from a flat whiteboard?

Comment: Why not just take them as a panorama http://www.wikihow.com/Take-Panorama-Photos-with-an-iPhone

Comment: This only works if the whiteboard drawing is very wide and not too high.  In practice, I need to take multiple pictures both horizontally and vertically to get one big drawing.

Comment: BTW Are you sure that your pictures are not deformed *from the start*? I don't know specifically about the iPhone but the small mobile lenses plus the software trying to compensate for that together are notoriously bad at handling perspective. Also, did you try both shooting the image when standing still (like a panorama) and with side-stepping?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) on your PC (Windows or Linux) or Mac to stitch together all the frames into one larger image, (I suspect that anything that stitched them together on the iPhone would likely leave you with an image that you could not clearly read on the screen.

Hugin is a free, FOSS, cross platform panorama toolkit that includes tools for perspective correction, amongst many others.  This does mean transferring the images to another machine but I am not aware of an iOS port, (someone may be working on one).